# Rails Database Lifecyle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, migration

I'm a SQL pro and a rails newbie.

I'm having trouble understanding how best to use the rails database abstraction.  Things I can do from a SQL command line in seconds seems overtly laborious in rails.

For example:

I generated a scaffold with several models and then tried to generate migrations to add associates to those models.
The generated migrations used 'create table' which won't work because the table already exists.
So I can either drop and recreate the table or use SQL 'ALTER TABLE' statements in the migration which makes me think I should have just created the database model by hand in the first place.

What are the benefits of using the rails data abstraction as apposed to doing the SQL with modeling tools and just using schema:dump and schema:load?

Answer (score 2):

Well there are many reasons why you want to use migrations over than just writing your `create table` and  `ALTER TABLE` in the console.

1.When I add a new table to column to a table there is a record that it happened and the rest of the developers on the team will know about it on the next commit with out having to send out email with complicated instructions to the ones that are not SQL pro

2.When you use a migration and you want to change databases from MySql to Postgres or anything else all you have to do is change the connection script

3. you can rollback your changes 
   Example:

   ```
   class AddSsl < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def up
       add_column :accounts, :ssl_enabled, :boolean, default: true
     end

     def down
       remove_column :accounts, :ssl_enabled
     end
   end
   ```

there are much more that you can do with migrations. 
I recommenced looking at 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html